# Visual Studio 2017 Ambient Test Indicator Not Showing Up

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-studio-2017

I'm assisting another developer who's using NUnit with Visual Studio 2017.  She's running unit tests and it appears that they're all getting run but for some reason on some of the tests, the ambient test indicators simply don't show up.

I am not totally sure of the version of NUnit but I think it's 2.6.x.  The tests are showing up in the test explorer (I've seen that issue before with VS 2017) and, as I say, it looks like they're actually running.

It looks like the ambient indicator doesn't show up for tests decorated with the [TestCase] attribute.  Is this a known issue?  She just wants to make sure this isn't indicating some other problem.

---

EDIT: I can reproduce this behavior with NUnit (3.8.1) and NUnit3TestAdapter (3.8.0) both installed via NuGet.  VS Professional 2017 v 15.3.5

Comment: To get a good answer, you really need to specify the version of both the NUnit framework and the NUnit VS adapter that she is using. You should also find out if the adapter is installed as a vsix or a nuget package.

Comment: Make sure to install the latest NUnit test adapter.

Comment: Do you mean the little checks next to the parts of the code that are covered by the unit tests? If so , it might be down to version (Community, Ultimate, etc...) of Visual Studio installed as I think the lower editions do not support this.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the suggestion but you'll note that I tested with VS 2017 Professional so I don't believe that's the issue.